# How to set the Interact timeframe for expect

Tags: expect

I am using expect via telnet to connect the box and then using expect script as follows:

`expect -c 'spawn -noecho telnet IP' exp_script`

On the expect script [exp_script] - Setting the user prompt and then using interact to interact the user to pass their cmd and stay on the prompt for further uses.

However I need to restrict the user to interact with box for certain time, the time frame will be dynamic and changes based on users.

So my question is how to restrict the users to interact the box via expect with certain timeframe only and then user should auto exit from box.

Highly appreciated for any help here!!

Comment: @glenn-jackman, Please suggest your thought here!!

Comment: So you want to kick user A off after 10 seconds, and user B after 20 seconds, something like that?

Comment: Yes, your are absolutely correct, the kick out time will be completely dynamic and it based on some other checks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the Tcl [`after`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/after.htm) command to schedule code to run after *X* milliseconds

```
spawn -noecho telnet IP

proc get_user_time_in_milliseconds {username} {
    # checks here
    set limit 5000   ;# => 5 seconds
    return $limit
}

proc byebye {spawn_id} {
    send_user "\n\nYour time is up. Bye!\n"
    exp_close $spawn_id
    exit
}

after [get_user_time_in_milliseconds $env(LOGNAME)] [list byebye $spawn_id]

# rest of expect code goes here.
interact
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @glenn-jackman! Let me try this logic and get back to you.

Comment: Also, how to collect the span ID which need to use in expect close, please

Comment: I don't understand your question. The last argument to `after` is a list which contains the spawn_id. That list will be executed as the command, and the spawn_id is the argument to the byebye proc.

Comment: Yes, got it !!!